# How to catch Unique constraint error in POSTGRESQL

Tags: c++, postgresql

If I create a table with a unique contraint, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
    did     integer,
    name    varchar(40) UNIQUE
);
```

What would happen if I try to enter an entry with the name that already exists. I tried to do so and it just quit without displaying any error message. Is there a way to check whether a new entry was actually inserted?

Comment: No data would be inserted, how the failure is interpreted from the db depends on what your using to access it? libpq/odbc etc?

Comment: I am using libpq, what would that return?

Comment: check the result of PQExec with PQresultStatus ; http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/libpq-exec.html

Answer (score 2):

If the insert failed than there should be error code set somewhere, readable by some method of the interface you're using - more details are definitely in documentation to your access library/module.

Alternatively you can change your insert to:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, name) values ( ... ) RETURNING did;
```

And if it didn't return anything - there has been error.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to insert record with name that already exists, you'll receive error message like this:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "distributors_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(aaa) already exists.
```

and record will not be inserted.
If you do it from allplcation level, the exception will be thrown with a message similar to this. It's up to the programmer how to handle this exception.

If your ID field is autogenerating (SERIAL or BIGSERIAL), and you insert just name, if you insert name which already exists, ID sequence will increase by 1, even if you didn't insert any record.

To avoid that you can make "SELECT" query before INSERT to check, it the record already exists. Possible to do all in one transaction, in pseudo-code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
int records = SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = 'aaa' FOR UPDATE;  //FOR UPDATE to lock the row from being read by other user until transaction finishes.
if (records == 0)
   INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 'aaa');
else
   MessageBox.Show("Record already exists");
COMMIT TRANSACCTION;
```

Comment: @mj82: please note that above code will sometimes return unique violation as well.

Comment: @depesz: can you tell exactly in what situation it may happen?

Comment: @mj83: if someone inserts a row after the SELECT has finished but before the INSERT has been executed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you're right, my mistake. How about corrected version: when you use SELECT FOR UPDATE, postgres locks row from being read by concurent user until transaction is finished and realeases the lock.

Comment: @mj82: no won't change a thing: If there is a row to be locked you won't insert anyway. If the count() returns zero, there was nothing to lock in the first place. The only way to avoid this would be a table lock

Comment: Avoiding gaps is ok, trying to actually prevent them is when it gets costly.  You can mostly avoid them by rolling back the above select / insert until it works etc.  But honestly, sequences shouldn't be customer facing anyway if you can help it.